# Drawing successive related samples from a Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, sampling

I have a question which describes a system where successive samples are drawn from a Gaussian distribution, and each sample is defined with the following relation.

$v_{k+1} = \gamma v_k + \eta_k$

where $\eta_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and $v_0 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_v^2)$. $\gamma$ is some positive constant.

Now, I have already figured out the joint probability distribution $P(v_k, v_{k+1})$, and I also know the probability distribution over $P(v_{k+1})$ is simply the marginal probability of $P(v_{k+1})$ derived from the joint probability of $P(v_k, v_{k+1})$.

The part of the question I am facing trouble with is where I need to find out the $\sigma_v$ such that the distribution of $v_k$ is independent of $k$. How would I go about approaching this?

**EDIT:** Is this an example of an AR(1) model?

Comment: $\sigma^2 = \gamma^2 \sigma^2 + \sigma^2_v$.

Comment: @zhoraster: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Assuming that $\eta_k$ are independent (which, I believe, is the case here), the variance of $v_{k+1}$ is the sum of variances of $\gamma v_k$ and $\eta_k$. Hence the equality.